# Is there a ProxyPass equivalent for IIS?

Tags: iis, ssl

I need to redirect one SSL site to another SSL site.

For example, I control https://sitea.michael.com but I want the traffic there to be forwarded to https://siteb.notinmycontrol.com

I don't control the DNS on notinmycontrol.com and anyway there's no way for them to install a michael.com cert on their servers.

If I'm running an Apache server, this works via mod_proxy and mod_ssl

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName sitea.michael.com
  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        SSLProxyEngine on
        ProxyPass / https://siteb.notinmycontrol.com/
        ProxyPassReverse / https://siteb.notinmycontrol.com/

        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
        ServerSignature On
</VirtualHost>
```

Is there an equivalent way to do this if I'm running an IIS server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are on IIS 7 or higher, you should be able to use [ARR](http://www.iis.net/download/ApplicationRequestRouting) as a [reverse proxy](http://blogs.iis.net/wonyoo/archive/2008/07/09/application-request-routing-arr-as-a-reverse-proxy.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Will this work for you?

http://www.at32.com/doc/rproxy.htm

Comment: @user18330 seems promising but the site and the download (and the fact that you have a really generic username) make it seem kind of sketchy... any further info?

Answer (score -1):

No there is no possibility to Reverse Proxy with IIS this is what ISA Server is for.